# Nhibernate Flush works commit doesn't

Tags: nhibernate

Sorry if my question doesn't have much detail but I'm new to nhibernate so not sure how to phrase. I'm wondering why calling session flush in a web application would not throw an error but Commit would.

I have this code normally:

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
session.Flush();
```

but if I call session.Commit() I get `a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` error

Doesn't Commit and Flush work the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NonUniqueObjectException`, you are experiencing, is thrown in scenarios, when:

- the *current* ISession instance was called to get by id, e.g. `.Get<TEntity>(id)`, and it keeps reference to this **item A**
- the *same* ISession instance is called to persist (`SaveOrUpdate`) an **item B** and

  - both items have the same key (`itemA.ID == itemB.ID`)
  - both are different references (`itemA != itemB`)

So, if this happens, the `NonUniqueObjectException` *("a different object with the same identifier...")* is thrown.

The `Flush()` and its configuration via `FlushMode` is the implementation of the concept of the detached persistence layer. We are working/interacting with a `session`, calling `Read` operations *(mostly executed immedietly or provided from cache)*, calling `Write` operations - which are queued. **Not** executed. **No** INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE is issued into DB engine.

Only when the `Flush()` is called, the session does the "synchronization" of the changes to DB. The advantage *(one of many)* is that NHibernate can manage the order of the write statements. *See:*

[9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

The order of issued statements:

- all entity insertions, in the same order the corresponding objects were saved using `ISession.Save()`
- all entity updates
- all collection deletions
- all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
- all collection insertions
- all entity deletions, in the same order the corresponding objects were deleted using `ISession.Delete()`

And finally, this is a snippet of the enum [FlushMode](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/FlushMode.cs), which does configure the `Flush()` call:

```
/// <summary> Represents a flushing strategy.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The flush process synchronizes database state with session state by detecting state
/// changes and executing SQL statements
/// </remarks>
[Serializable]
public enum FlushMode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Special value for unspecified flush mode (like <see langword="null" /> in Java).
    /// </summary>
    Unspecified = -1,
        /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is never flushed unless <c>Flush()</c> is explicitly
    /// called by the application. This mode is very efficient for read only
    /// transactions
    /// </summary>
    Never = 0,
        /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is flushed when <c>Transaction.Commit()</c> is called
    /// </summary>
    Commit = 5,
        /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to
    /// ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.
    /// </summary>
    Auto = 10,
        /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ISession"/> is flushed before every query. This is
    /// almost always unnecessary and inefficient.
    /// </summary>
    Always = 20
}
```

Comment: Very thorough and authoritative answer.

Comment: The only odd thing now is that if I set FlushMode.Auto, I don't get that error when I do session.Transaction.Commit but when I do FlushMode.Never, call session.Flush(), and then do session...Commit, i get the error. Do you know why?

Comment: In general, I would strongly suggest: use 1) Commit or 2) Never with explicit Flush() before Commit. Write operations should be sitting in one session, Read in onether (e.g. different web request). The whole operation should be committed or not. So, AUTO would mostly not be the best way to go. I would say. I am using the never and explicit Flush for a long time ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be because I had FlushMode.Commit and not FlushMode.Auto. Not 100% sure why