# Why isn't NHibernate deleting from the database?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am having an issue with NHibernate not deleting rows from the database. Nhibernate is saving and updating to the same database without issue.

After running SQL profiler it appears that there is no delete SQL being sent to the database - which makes me think it's a configuration issue but nothing is standing out to me...

**Config**

Nhibernate version : 3.3.1.4000
FluentNHibernate Version : 1.3.0.733
SQL Server Version : 2008R2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">IntermediateDatabase</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">500</property>

    <!-- Mapping assemblies -->
    <!-- Can't map it for Fluent NHibernate here; instead, load the mapping assembly in Global.asax.cs.
        If you're still using HBMs, you can use the mapping here or pass the assembly via Global.asax.cs
        as well, just like you can do with the Fluent NHibernate assembly(s). -->

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, thre is NO way, how to configure NHibernate to INSERT and UPDATE but never DELETE. I would bet that this issues is related to the application level. The most supsected to me, is that DELETE operation is not wrapped in transaction or it does not have call session.Flus()... could you show your Delete code? and explain how it is wrapped in transaction?

Comment: or check that you don't have `mutable=false` but if you can update rows then I don't suspect that...

Comment: Can you also provide mapping?

Comment: Did you confirm that the data is deleted ? Maybe profiler doesn't show the code because you are making batch updates via batch_size. Just check if the delete does occur or not after you commit the trx

Comment: Hey @RadimKöhler

The delete is not wrapped in a transactionScope by the looks of things:

  public void Delete(T entity) {
            using (Session) {
                this.Session.Delete(entity);
            }
        }

Might this be the issue? The update is:

  public T SaveOrUpdate(T entity) {
            using (Session) {

                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
                    Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                    scope.Complete();
                }

                return entity;
            }
        }

Comment: @Rippo I don't have mutable set thanks

Comment: @DoanVanTuan are you asking for the HBM? This is in Fluent thanks

Comment: @ReverseBlade the data is not deleted thanks

Comment: @Comanighttrain Then please add your fluent mapping. They are the same (with xml mapping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information from your comment... It seems that your working method is like:

UPDATE

```
public T SaveOrUpdate(T entity) 
{ 
    using (Session) 
    { 
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        { 
            Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity); scope.Complete(); 
        } 
        return entity; 
    } 
}
```

And this is absolutely correct... because your session FlushMode would most likely be:

```
session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
```

Pleae see more details here: [Nhibernate Flush works commit doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620894/)

DELETE

But the poor sister `Delete()` is not fully supported as mighty *Update()*

```
public void Delete(T entity) 
{ 
    using (Session) 
    { 
        this.Session.Delete(entity); 
    } 
 }
```

So, while even for `Delete()` the session `FlushMode` is still hooked on a **transaction** commit ... there is no transaction. And that's for sure *(well most likely)* the real reason *(as suspected)*

Summary, treat both, `Update` and `Delete` as the twins... and give them the same care - i.e. transaction

Comment: Thanks Radim - you nailed it :)

Answer (score 1):

If the deleted object is a part of collection of another object then in the mapping give .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() and just remove the item from the collection, then nhibernate will send the delete statement to DB.

Comment: thanks but this is a single object not a part of a collection

Comment: Did you defined the id parameter in the mapping ?